# Create a user with Active Directory

Tags: c#, active-directory

I'm trying to create a user in Active Directory, using a function I adapted from some sample code I have found.

```
public bool crearUsuario(string usu, string pass, string path)
{
    string path = @"LDAP://" + path;

    //string oGUID = string.Empty;
    try { 

        DirectoryEntry entrada  = new DirectoryEntry(path);

        DirectoryEntry nuevoUsuario = entrada.Children.Add("CN=" + usu, "users");
        nuevoUsuario.Properties["samAccountName"].Value = usu;
        nuevoUsuario.CommitChanges();
        //oGUID = nuevoUsuario.Guid.ToString();

        nuevoUsuario.Invoke("SetPassword", new object[] { pass });
        nuevoUsuario.CommitChanges();
        entrada.Close();
        nuevoUsuario.Close();

        return true;
    }
    catch (System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryServicesCOMException E)
    {
        //E.Message.ToString();
        return false;
    }
    //return oGUID;
}
```

The original code returned a string (`oGUID`), but I only need a boolean.

My question is, why do they use that string? I only need `true` or `false` values, so I don't know if I need to return a string instead of a boolean value.

Comment: How you implement your code is up to you. In general though, I wouldn't return a boolean to indicate success or failure. Instead, I would let the exception bubble up to the location that can handle it, or I would create a distinct object to represent success or failure. For example, create an interface IUserCreationResult and then create two classes that implement that interface SuccessfulUserCreationResult and FailedUserCreationResult. Your failure class might have an additional property to give context on *why* it failed.

Comment: This is a bit speculative, but the intent of the original method was probably the same as yours, but the original coder maybe needed the user's GUID as well. Essentially, an empty string returned is like a false value and a non-empty string is like a true value, with the added bonus that you also have the GUID value.

Comment: We can't possibly guess why that code returns a string, especially since we don't know where it came from.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

String seems an odd choice to me, also: I would have returned the raw `Guid` type. But the reason to return a string, guid, or other key, is there's an expectation you'll want to **do something** with that user account after you create it. Returning the new key as part of the original creation function is very likely to save you some work later.

If you know you won't be in that situation, it's perfectly fine to just return `true`/`false`... keeping in mind the comment on the question about letting the exception bubble up also has merit.